# Using keyCode to pair keydown and keyup events

Tags: javascript

I want to keep track of which keys are pressed at a given time, like so:

```
var keys = {};
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
$(document.body).on('keyup', function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});
```

However, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) it looks like `keyCode` is deprecated, and suggests `key`. From testing on Chrome, it looks like `key` is `undefined`. The documentation also describes `which` but I am unsure as to what the differences are.

**Is keyCode the right thing to use here? I don't care which keys are down, only that I know that some keys are pressed. I also can't use the `input` event.**

Comment: Try using `console.log(e)` to see the e-_properties_

Comment: "From testing on Chrome, it looks like key is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a fallback mechanism which handles the advise from MDN first and than falls back to the older solutions.
But if you are using jQuery you should use the [provided methods](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to get the key-code

```
// jquery
$(document.body).on('keyup', function(e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
});

// vanilla
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    delete keys[(e.key && e.keyCode.charCodeAt(0)) || e.which || e.keyCode];
}, true);
```

However this will only be true for printable characters and needs a deeper investigation of the problem usually.

Comment: Why though? I can already see these parameters exist from the documentation. And why this order? I really just want the hardware scan code, to borrow from my win32 experience.